# Merging two columns of words having small and capital letters in r

Tags: r, merge, cpu-word

I have two data frames and I want to merge them using two columns that are like below:

```
a <- data.frame(A = c("Ali", "Should Be", "Calif")))
b <- data.frame(B = c("ALI", "CALIF", "SHOULD BE"))
```

Could you please let me know if it is possible to do it in r?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example and the expected output? What are the other columns of the two datasets?

Comment: The other columns are just some numbers.

Comment: And those are the ones you need to merge?

Comment: `merge(df, df1, by.x = "A", by.y = "B")` ?

Comment: `colnames(A) <- tolower(colnames(A))` and similarly for `B`.

Comment: first need to transform the two columns, preferably, `df1$A=toupper(df1$A)` then merge the two `merge(df,df1,by.x="A",by.y="B")`

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to decapitalize your character values using `tolower` from `base R` and then do a `merge`:

```
library(dplyr) # for mutating

df1 <- df1 %>%
       mutate(A = tolower(A))

df2 <- df2 %>%
       mutate(B = tolower(B))

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "A", by.y = "B")

df3
          A
1       ali
2     calif
3 should be
```

Is this what you needed?

**Edit**: The `dplyr` bit is of course not necessary. If everything is to be done in `base R`, `df1$A=tolower(df1$A)` and `df2$B=tolower(df2$B)` - as suggested in the comments - work just as well.